# Filter built with Regex cannot target more than one word at a time (Django 2.1.5)

Tags: python, regex, django, python-3.x

I have a custom filter that highlights the keywords that the user had put into the search bar (like on Google search). However, as of now, it only highlights the last word of the keywords. For example, if the keywords are "American film industry", only "industry" will be highlighted. But I want all three words to be highlighted whenever and wherever they are present on the webpage (even if they aren't next to each other). To treat the keywords string as individual words, I have split the keywords:

```
def highlight(value, search_term, autoescape=True):
    search_term_list = search_term.split()
    search_term_word = ''
    for search_term_word in search_term_list:
        pattern = re.compile(re.escape(search_term_word), re.IGNORECASE)
        new_value = pattern.sub('<span class="highlight">\g<0></span>', value)
    return mark_safe(new_value)
```

Any idea why the filter only highlights the last word and how to make the code work?

Comment: What does `mark_safe` do?

Comment: Replace all `new_value` with `value`. You use the unchanged `value` when highlighting each subsequent `search_term_word`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it works! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative to the proposed solution by @WiktorStribiżew

```
# import re

def highlight(value, search_term):
    pattern = r'{}'.format(search_term.replace(' ', '|'))
    return re.sub(pattern, '<span class="highlight">\g<0></span>', value)

highlight('Hello one world', 'one world')
# 'Hello <span class="highlight">one</span> <span class="highlight">world</span>'
```